# Spivak, Ch 2 Prologue, Problem 12d: is there a systematic way to find two irrational numbers whose sum and multiplication result in rational number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question in Spivak is: are there two irrational numbers whose sum and product are both rational? Below is my solution, and my question is if there is a more systematic way of finding the two irrational numbers.

Assume:
$$a,b \in Q'\tag{1}$$
$$a+b =r_1\tag{2}$$
$$ab = r_2\tag{3}$$
$$r1, r2 \in Q$$
Then,
$$a=r_1-b \rightarrow (r_1-b)b = r_2 \rightarrow b^2-r_1b+r_2=0$$
$$\triangle = r_1^2-4r_2 \geq0 \rightarrow r_1^2 \geq 4r_2$$
So, at this point we know the relationship between $r_1$ and $r_2$ necessary to satisfy (2) and (3), but this includes rational and irrational options for $a$ and $b$ and we only want irrational ones.

Is the only way to proceed here to make guesses?

For example, $r_1=0 \rightarrow r_2 \leq 0$ and we have $a+b=0 \rightarrow a=-b\ and\ ab=r_2$. We can now guess an $r_2$ and hope we find irrational values for $a$ and $b$. $$r_2 = -3 \rightarrow -b^2=-3 \rightarrow b^2=3 \rightarrow b=\pm \sqrt{3}$$.So, we have two solutions for $a,b$: $a=-\sqrt{3}, b=\sqrt{3}$ and $a=\sqrt{3}, b=-\sqrt{3}$.

We could likewise guess different values for $r_1$ and $r_2$ and obtain other solutions.

Is this the only way to obtain these solutions or is there a more systematic way?

Answer (score 1):

How about
$$a+\sqrt b$$
and $$a-\sqrt b$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{Q},\sqrt b\notin \mathbb{Q} $ ? That seems the simplest answer to me.